# php variable scope

Tags: php, scope

i'm confused about the php variable scope.
such as:

```
while(true){
    $var = "yes , it is a test!";
  }
  printf($var)
```

the `$var` is defined in while statement scope , how could we get it outside it's scope ? and i can't find explanation on the document .

i wonder how php deal with it's scope .

Comment: `while (true)` is an infinity loop...

Comment: Please go back and review your old questions. If there are good sollutions, mark them as accepted using the green 'check'. If there are none (which i doubt), please consider answering your own questions with how you solved the problems in the end. Furthermore, try and check your formatting.

Comment: This might be a useful starting point: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: how about switch() case statement? Does it create its own scope like a function? Thanks~

Comment: if you want to create a new local scope http://stackoverflow.com/a/33460057/3160597

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `while(true)` you will not get out of the while, so it wouldn't matter. But if you would have a real expression, something like this (*this is a useless example, i know*)

```
$i=0
while($i<10){ 
   $var = "yes , it is a test!"; 
   $i++;
 } 
 printf($var);
```

Will just work. 
There is no special "while" variable scope, the printf will print your string. check : http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 8):

`while` is not a function. scope of variable refers to variable inside `functions` and `classes`

Answer (score 6):

In PHP, a while loop doesn't create a new [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). So it will be available in the function

Answer (score 2):

Loop does not have any scope in PHP. variable is simply available outside the loop.

just `echo` outside the loop;

`echo $var;`

Answer (score 0):

For the complete answer check the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Notice: Different PHP-version behave differently on $GLOBALS, $_SERVER ($HTTP_SERVER_VARS [deprecated]) and $_SESSION. Please check that. Old PHP page are not always upwards compatible. You should check that.