# Variable scope in for-loop and while-loop

Tags: php, python, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new in PHP, I don't understand why the final result of the code below is '233' instead of '231', isn't the $a in foreach is a temp variable?

```
<?php
    $a = '1';
    $c = array('2', '3');
    foreach($c as $a){
        echo $a ;
    }
    echo $a;
?>
```

Can anyone help? Thks.

Updated 2014-11-28
Now I know what was my problem. As the accepted answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631962/php-variable-scope#answer-5632019) have pointed out, neither the `foreach` nor the `while` act like `functions`, they are just normal sentences just like `$a='3';`. So now I know this is my misunderstanding and it's not just about `php`, as I've tried in python, it's the same.

```
a = 123
b = [1, 2, 3]
for a in b:
    print a
print a
```

Comment: Because you redeclare $a in your while loop.. making it become the last value of the array..

Comment: @Naruto So you mean that the $a is not act like a temp variable?

Comment: @Naruto Miss understanding.(*_*). Thanks

Comment: yeah. if you change $b = '1' and echo $b at the last part, then you got 231.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$a` on line 1 and the `$a` in the `foreach()` loop is one and the same object. And after the loop ends, `$a` has the value `3`, which is `echo`ed in the last statement.
According to php.net:

> For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope.

Only in a function does the variable scope is different.
This would produce your desired result '231':

```
$a = '1';
$c = array('2', '3');
function iterate($temp)
{
    foreach($temp as $a)
        echo $a ;
}
iterate($c)
echo $a;
```

Because in the `iterate()` function, `$a` is independent of the `$a` of the calling code.
More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2):

The `$a` in your `foreach` loop overrides the `$a` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have taken same name of variable in the `foreach` loop. your foreach is working as:

1. on first iteration: it assigning the value 2 means `$c[0]`'s value to `$a`.
2. on next iteration: it assigning the value 3 means `$c[1]`'s value to `$a`.
3. After that the value of `$a` has become 3 instead if 1.

That's why result is 233. not 231.