# foreach loop value outside of the loop

Tags: php

PHP return foreach loop value outside of the loop

```
$checkmissing = array();
if ($data){
    foreach ( $data as $curDay ){
        $checkmissing['value1'] = $curDay['value1'];
        $checkmissing['value2'] = $curDay['value2'];
        $checkmissing['value3'] = $curDay['value3'];
        $checkmissing['value4'] = $curDay['value4'];
        $checkmissing['value5'] = $curDay['value5'];
        $checkmissing['value6'] = $curDay['value6'];
        $checkmissing['value7'] = $curDay['value7'];
    }
}
return $checkmissing;
```

I try this it not return anything

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631962/php-variable-scope.

Comment: show your `$data` array.

Comment: How are you verifying that it is _"not returning anything"_? Is `$data` an array? Where is it defined?

Comment: If you have $data array, you should use count in if condition like
`if(count($data) > 0){ ...}`