# What is the (syntactic or semantic) meaning of un-prefixed curly braces in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, semantics

Today I saw a source code like this:

```
<?php
{
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../config/autoload.php';
    $cfg = new Cfg('mypage');
}
?>
```

It seems to work but why would you put senseless curly braces around a piece of code? Is there any meaning in it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14971123/use-curly-brackets-to-structure-code-in-php

Comment: Thanks this  explains a lot! Still not even somebody commented a reasonable argument to do something like this. So can I assume there is entirely no point in doing something like this (except code folding or wrapping a block for a semantic comment)?